# Adding Map Layers using GGPLOT - Colorizing Adds Errors

Tags: r, maps

I am doing a mapping project, that I thought would be rather simple in R. Using the Freedom House scores for freedom, I created a map that colorized each country by it's freedom score. Seemed simple enough; dataframe ends up with a column for color that's stored in a hex value.

Code to plot the map as follows:

```
 p <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = merged_world_data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = color), color="#333333") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(text = element_text(color = '#EEEEEE')
    ,axis.ticks = element_blank()
    ,axis.text = element_blank()
    ,panel.grid = element_blank()
    ,panel.background = element_rect(fill = '#333333')
    ,plot.background = element_rect(fill = '#333333')) + 
scale_fill_identity()
```

Fill is based on the "color" column in my dataframe, which is stored as a HEX value.

[image: Colorized Map by Score]

This is just the first part of my problem though, as I want to be able to plot points of interest onto the map. One layer I want to add is maritime shipping chokepoints. I have them stored in their own dataframe, df_chokepoints.

I added them to the code as follows:

```
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = merged_world_data, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, fill = color), color="#333333") +
  labs(x = NULL, y = NULL) +
  theme(text = element_text(color = '#EEEEEE')
    ##,plot.title = element_text(size = 28)
    ##,plot.subtitle = element_text(size = 14)
    ,axis.ticks = element_blank()
    ,axis.text = element_blank()
    ,panel.grid = element_blank()
    ,panel.background = element_rect(fill = '#333333')
    ,plot.background = element_rect(fill = '#333333')) +
scale_fill_identity() +
geom_point(data = df_chokepoints, aes(x = Longitude, y = Latitude), size = 5, shape = 23)
```

As soon as I plot the new ggplot with the geom_point line, I get this error:

> Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale

Comment: Have you read - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278153/plotting-with-ggplot2-error-discrete-value-supplied-to-continuous-scale-on-c